# Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management Service (VMMS) not listed in Services

Tags: virtual, hyper-v, hypervisor

I recently installed Hyper-V on my Windows 11 home machine. All was working fine until one day I was deleting, from the Hyper-V Manager, what I thought were my created virtual machines but I think I also deleted the VMMS? I don't know how I did this and the issue is I don't know how to get it back?
The hyper-V manager now looks like this:
[image: Hyper-V manager]

The services window looks like this:
[image: Windows service]

The windows features window looks like this:
[image: Windows Feature]

I got hyper-V onto my home edition by running the following script

```
pushd "%~dp0"
dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\*Hyper-V*.mum >hv.txt
for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . hv.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"
del hv.txt
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All /LimitAccess /ALL
pause
```

Now when I try to create a new virtual machine, I get the following error:
[image: error message]

I have tried the following:

1. Removing the Hyper-V windows feature and then adding it back in;
2. Re-running the powershell script;
3. From Hyper-V Manager selecting the 'Connect to Servier...' option and then selecting local machine but I get the following error:
   [image: manager error message]

Most of the suggestions online assume the VMMS is in the services window and it just needs starting, or all options in the Windows Feature for hyper-v should be checked (which they are), or to disable any other hypervisors

I did have VirtualBox and VMWare workstation installed (and they all worked fine side-by-side). I have now removed these from the controlpanel/Program and Features. But this has had no effect.

I don't know how to re-install the VMMS so any advice would be really appreciated. Thanks